# How to zoom a MapView so it always includes two geopoints?

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have two geo points that vary intermittently, and want the MapView to resize and translate to make sure both points are always visible. I can easily re-centre the map on the point mid-way between the two, but how do I set the zoom level to ensure my two points are visible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this and see:

```
double latitudeSpan = Math.round(Math.abs(firstLat - 
                secLat));
double longitudeSpan = Math.round(Math.abs(firstLong - 
                secLong));

double currentLatitudeSpan = (double)mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
double currentLongitudeSpan = (double)mapView.getLongitudeSpan();

double ratio = currentLongitudeSpan/currentLatitudeSpan;
if(longitudeSpan < (double)(latitudeSpan+2E7) * ratio){
    longitudeSpan = ((double)(latitudeSpan+2E7) * ratio);
}

mapController.zoomToSpan((int)(latitudeSpan*2), (int)(longitudeSpan*2));                
mapView.invalidate();
```

Comment: Hm, this did not work for me -- always set zoom level 0 (i.e. showed me the whole world map). I removed the `if (longitudeSpan < ...){...}` adaption of longitudeSpan and now it works fine. Also remember that firstLat,firstLong,secLat,secLong are from GeoPoints, i.e. original lat/long values * 1E6.

Answer (score 5):

Check out his answer in a different post:
[Google Map V2 how to set ZoomToSpan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14747037/google-map-v2-how-to-set-zoomtospan)

It solves it without much hassle. Note that you can only use that function AFTER the map has been loaded at least once. If not use function with specified map size on screen

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(new LatLng(CURRENTSTOP.latitude, CURRENTSTOP.longitude))
                    .include(new LatLng(MYPOSITION.latitude, MYPOSITION.longitude)).build();

Point displaySize = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);

map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, displaySize.x, 250, 30));
```

Works like a charm and very dynamic!

Comment: Works well when you have 2 or more points, when you have just one you should use another solution.

Answer (score 0):

in the new Maps API (v2) you can do it this way:

```
LatLng southwest = new LatLng(Math.min(laglng1.latitude, laglng2.latitude), Math.min(laglng1.longitude, laglng2.longitude));
LatLng northeast = new LatLng(Math.max(laglng1.latitude, laglng2.latitude), Math.max(laglng1.longitude, laglng2.longitude));
googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(new LatLngBounds(southwest, northeast),500,500, 0));
```