# Google Map V2 how to set ZoomToSpan?

Tags: android

As title, in map v1 i could use

```
mapController.zoomToSpan(..., ..., ...);
```

to include all markers on the screen.

Dose map V2 has the same method?

---

2013/2/22 edit:

first, get all LatLng points you want to involve on the screen.

Assume if you have 3 LatLng points, use

```
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder().include(point1)
                    .include(point2).include(point3).build();

mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer on this?  I also cannot find a ZoomToSpan equivalent.

Comment: Move your edit to answer and accept it. Some users seem to not get it you answered yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**Try This**

```
  map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)).setVisible(true);

  // Move the camera instantly to location with a zoom of 15.
  map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15));

  // Zoom in, animating the camera.
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will be use full to you.

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap map;
Bundle extras;

LatLng latlng;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google);

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        unit_long = extras.getString("unit_long");
        unit_lat = extras.getString("unit_lat");

    }

    latlng = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble("19.25252"),
            Double.parseDouble("23.25252525"));

    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng)
            .title("Location").snippet("I am here")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker)));

    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latlng, 15));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.use this line in your code 
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(14), 2000, null);
    // map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

map V2

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
 GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager()
                                            .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
 map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

     if (map != null) {
        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);
     }
 }
```

you can change the value of 12,  that is the zooming level of map load.
Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Fews methods of Google map V2 can do the same things :

```
static CameraUpdate  newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int padding)
```

> Returns a CameraUpdate that transforms the camera such that the specified latitude/longitude bounds are centered on screen at the greatest possible zoom level.

```
static CameraUpdate newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds bounds, int width, int height, int padding)
```

> Returns a CameraUpdate that transforms the camera such that the specified latitude/longitude bounds are centered on screen within a bounding box of specified dimensions at the greatest possible zoom level.

```
static CameraUpdate  newLatLngZoom(LatLng latLng, float zoom)
```

> Returns a CameraUpdate that moves the center of the screen to a latitude and longitude specified by a LatLng object, and moves to the given zoom level.

Here is an example to use one of them :

```
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(geoPoint, zoom));
```